# Cumputing indicators with a DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Can you please help me on calculating indicators for a DataFrame :

The code below works fine for a serie (index dates and one column for returns of the asset) : BUT not for a DataFrame

"" r is the data set i use in the function ( the index are the dates and the columns are the asset's name and returns )

```
def drawdown(r):

    wealth_index = 1000*(1+r).cumprod()

    previous_peaks = wealth_index.cummax()

    drawdown = (wealth_index - previous_peaks)/previous_peaks

    amount_drawdown = wealth_index - previous_peaks

    return pd.DataFrame({"Wealth": wealth_index,

    "Previous Peak": previous_peaks,

    "Max Drawdown in %": drawdown*100,

    "Drawdown Amount": amount_drawdown})
```

For DataFrame : i have tried to index the output DataFrame but i have it wrong.

```
def drawdown(r):

    wealth_index = 1000*(1+r).cumprod()

    previous_peaks = wealth_index.cummax()

    drawdown = (wealth_index - previous_peaks)/previous_peaks

    amount_drawdown = wealth_index - previous_peaks

    return pd.DataFrame({"Wealth": wealth_index,

    "Previous Peak": previous_peaks,

    "Max Drawdown in %": drawdown*100,

    "Drawdown Amount": amount_drawdown}, index=r.columns)
```

Can you please help...

Comment: can you post a sample of your dataframe? Maybe 10 rows or so...

Comment: date,Convertible Arbitrage,CTA Global,Distressed Securities,Emerging Markets,Equity Market Neutral,Event Driven,Fixed Income Arbitrage,Global Macro,Long/Short Equity,Merger Arbitrage,Relative Value,Short Selling,Funds Of Funds
31/01/1997,1.19,3.93,1.78,7.91,1.89,2.13,1.91,5.73,2.81,1.50,1.80,-1.66,3.17
28/02/1997,1.23,2.98,1.22,5.25,1.01,0.84,1.22,1.75,-0.06,0.34,1.18,4.26,1.06
31/03/1997,0.78,-0.21,-0.12,-1.20,0.16,-0.23,1.09,-1.19,-0.84,0.60,0.10,7.78,-0.77
30/04/1997,0.86,-1.70,0.30,1.19,1.19,-0.05,1.30,1.72,0.84,-0.01,1.22,-1.29,0.09

Comment: this is the csv, i convert it to period to use it in the formula, and slice one of the columns to giver it a serie, but with all the columns i have an error

Comment: i use parse dates of course while importing

Comment: I need two indexes, first the name of the columns of my data then the dates for each column name : name1 / date 1 date 2 date 3 ... then the result for name1, name2 / date 1 date 2 date 3... then the result for name2 and so forth

Comment: Please add the needed information to the _question_, not to the comments - otherwise it is difficult to see.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I missed your last comment, looks like you want a multi-index Dataframe as the final out put. I believe this is correct for your requirements
(Obviously fill in the file path and name of your CSV file inside of def ind())

```
def ind():
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/mre/Desktop/test.csv', parse_dates=True) 
    return drawdownDF(df)

def drawdownSeries(r, dates, col):

    wealth_index = 1000*(1+r).cumprod()

    previous_peaks = wealth_index.cummax()

    drawdown = (wealth_index - previous_peaks)/previous_peaks

    amount_drawdown = wealth_index - previous_peaks

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Group": col, "date" : dates, "Wealth": wealth_index,

    "Previous Peak": previous_peaks,

    "Max Drawdown in %": drawdown*100,

    "Drawdown Amount": amount_drawdown}) 

    return df


def drawdownDF(r):
#    dfs = {}
    dfs = []
    for col in r.columns[1:]:
        collist = [col]*len(r['date'])
        dfs.append(drawdownSeries(r[col], r['date'], collist))
    finalPD = pd.concat(dfs)
    finalPD.set_index(['Group', 'date'], inplace=True)
    return finalPD
```

Output:

```
In [104]: ind()
Out[104]: 
                                   Drawdown Amount  Max Drawdown in %  \
Group                  date                                             
Convertible Arbitrage  31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
CTA Global             31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997      -4120.49400           -21.0000   
                       30/04/1997     -30472.03420          -155.3000   
Distressed Securities  31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997       -740.59200           -12.0000   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
Emerging Markets       31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997     -66825.00000          -120.0000   
                       30/04/1997     -80078.62500          -143.8000   
Equity Market Neutral  31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
Event Driven           31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997      -1324.61600           -23.0000   
                       30/04/1997      -1546.34520           -26.8500   
Fixed Income Arbitrage 31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
Global Macro           31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997     -22023.92500          -119.0000   
                       30/04/1997     -28072.17600          -151.6800   
Long/Short Equity      31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997       -228.60000            -6.0000   
                       31/03/1997      -3236.97600           -84.9600   
                       30/04/1997      -2755.63584           -72.3264   
Merger Arbitrage       31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       30/04/1997        -53.60000            -1.0000   
Relative Value         31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
Short Selling          31/01/1997          0.00000            -0.0000   
                       28/02/1997      -2811.60000           426.0000   
                       31/03/1997     -29820.64800          4518.2800   
                       30/04/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
Funds Of Funds         31/01/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       28/02/1997          0.00000             0.0000   
                       31/03/1997      -6614.45400           -77.0000   
                       30/04/1997      -6436.63686           -74.9300   

                                   Previous Peak       Wealth  
Group                  date                                    
Convertible Arbitrage  31/01/1997     2190.00000   2190.00000  
                       28/02/1997     4883.70000   4883.70000  
                       31/03/1997     8692.98600   8692.98600  
                       30/04/1997    16168.95396  16168.95396  
CTA Global             31/01/1997     4930.00000   4930.00000  
                       28/02/1997    19621.40000  19621.40000  
                       31/03/1997    19621.40000  15500.90600  
                       30/04/1997    19621.40000 -10850.63420  
Distressed Securities  31/01/1997     2780.00000   2780.00000  
                       28/02/1997     6171.60000   6171.60000  
                       31/03/1997     6171.60000   5431.00800  
                       30/04/1997     7060.31040   7060.31040  
Emerging Markets       31/01/1997     8910.00000   8910.00000  
                       28/02/1997    55687.50000  55687.50000  
                       31/03/1997    55687.50000 -11137.50000  
                       30/04/1997    55687.50000 -24391.12500  
Equity Market Neutral  31/01/1997     2890.00000   2890.00000  
                       28/02/1997     5808.90000   5808.90000  
                       31/03/1997     6738.32400   6738.32400  
                       30/04/1997    14756.92956  14756.92956  
Event Driven           31/01/1997     3130.00000   3130.00000  
                       28/02/1997     5759.20000   5759.20000  
                       31/03/1997     5759.20000   4434.58400  
                       30/04/1997     5759.20000   4212.85480  
Fixed Income Arbitrage 31/01/1997     2910.00000   2910.00000  
                       28/02/1997     6460.20000   6460.20000  
                       31/03/1997    13501.81800  13501.81800  
                       30/04/1997    31054.18140  31054.18140  
Global Macro           31/01/1997     6730.00000   6730.00000  
                       28/02/1997    18507.50000  18507.50000  
                       31/03/1997    18507.50000  -3516.42500  
                       30/04/1997    18507.50000  -9564.67600  
Long/Short Equity      31/01/1997     3810.00000   3810.00000  
                       28/02/1997     3810.00000   3581.40000  
                       31/03/1997     3810.00000    573.02400  
                       30/04/1997     3810.00000   1054.36416  
Merger Arbitrage       31/01/1997     2500.00000   2500.00000  
                       28/02/1997     3350.00000   3350.00000  
                       31/03/1997     5360.00000   5360.00000  
                       30/04/1997     5360.00000   5306.40000  
Relative Value         31/01/1997     2800.00000   2800.00000  
                       28/02/1997     6104.00000   6104.00000  
                       31/03/1997     6714.40000   6714.40000  
                       30/04/1997    14905.96800  14905.96800  
Short Selling          31/01/1997     -660.00000   -660.00000  
                       28/02/1997     -660.00000  -3471.60000  
                       31/03/1997     -660.00000 -30480.64800  
                       30/04/1997     8839.38792   8839.38792  
Funds Of Funds         31/01/1997     4170.00000   4170.00000  
                       28/02/1997     8590.20000   8590.20000  
                       31/03/1997     8590.20000   1975.74600  
                       30/04/1997     8590.20000   2153.56314
```